# How to make the items in a WPF ListBox wrap horizontally and vertically

Tags: wpf, user-interface

I want to show a list of thumbnails, and allow the user to choose one. A `ListBox` seemed an obvious choice, setting the template to include the thumbnail and description.

The following code does this correctly...

```
<ListBox Margin="5"
         Name="BackgroundsLb">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Border Margin="5"
              BorderBrush="Black"
              BorderThickness="1">
        <StackPanel Margin="5">
          <Image Source="{Binding Path=Data, Converter={StaticResource BytesToImageVC}}"
                 Width="150"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
      </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

However, this displays the thumbnails vertically, one per row, as is normal for a `ListBox`. Given that the thumbnails are only 150 pixels wide, I would like to show them in something more like a grid, but (ideally) in a way so that the number of columns adapts to the size of the window.

I tried replacing the `ListBox` with an `ItemsControl`, adding in the following...

```
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

...and it displayed exactly how I wanted it, but the `ItemsControl` does not allow selection, so is no use for my purpose.

Is there a way to achieve a flexible, selectable display that fills the horizontal space, and breaks onto a new row according to the size of the window?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `ItemsPanelTemplate` in a `ListBox` just the same as you are using one in the `ItemsControl`. The difference I think you're seeing is that `ListBox` uses scroll bars by default rather than wrapping the content. Basically the content is allowed to grow forever, so you never get the wrap. Instead you get a scrollbar. The good news is you can disable this behavior. The following should give you a horizontal wrap, where new rows are created as needed.

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: That's completely brilliant, thanks. I'd tried using a `WrapPanel`, but without disabling the horizontal scrollbar, it didn't help. That extra trick did the job. Thanks again.